# <select> Tag not working inside bootstrap dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to place select tag inside bootstrap dropdown. When i try to select any option the select tag get closed. Any idea why is this happening. I want to acieve this

[image]

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-info editbtn" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><label>Label</label><input class="form-control InputRequired" type="text"></li>
        <li><label>Placeholder</label><input class="form-control InputRequired" type="text"></li>
        <li><label>Type</label>
            <select class="form-control">
                <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                </select>
            </li><br>
        <button   class="btn btn-info save">Save</button>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: add working fiddle to understand practically your issue

Comment: Wrong approach entirely. You're not taking into account the user experience. It is well established that with a hierarchy like this, it is best to display secondary sets as such. See: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/multi-level-dropdown-menu-bs3

Comment: @BradEvans I have attached an image how can i achieve this by not using select inside dropdown ?

Comment: @TechBreak i have found this fiddle but i guess he is using some plugin. http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/5c9b9t9n/

Comment: @Abid yes it is achieved using a popular plugin i.e. selectpicker. Is there any restriction at your side to not use that?

Comment: @TechBreak this is a very small project. I was wondering if i could do it without using any plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Although you shouldn't use a dropdown menu this way, if you absolutely want to do this, you can manually trigger the dropdown toggle yourself.

The reason why the dropdown gets cleared is because `click.bs.dropdown.data-api` event on `document` is getting triggered as you click on the `select` element.

This can be avoided if the dropdown isn't triggered using `[data-toggle="dropdown"]` selector.

The drawback is you can't close the dropdown by clicking outside the dropdown menu. Of course, you can always add additional event to close it but that's up to you.

```js
(function($, window, document) {
  $("#dropdown").on("click", function() {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass("open");
  });

  $("#dropdown-save").on("click", function() {
    $(this).closest(".dropdown").removeClass("open");
  });
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button id="dropdown" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button">Dropdown Example
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
    <li>
      <label for="label">Label</label>
      <input type="text" id="label">
    </li>
    <li>
      <select>
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      </select>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button id="dropdown-save">Save</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```